# Loop in std::set by index

Tags: c++, indexing, set, std

I'm making a program that handles dynamic graphs. Nodes and arcs are two classes, they are memorized in an array in the graph object, and are all indexed by custom ids (which are that item's position in the array).
Each arc has the ids of the 2 nodes it connects, each node has a list of the ids of all arcs its connected to. (all stored in sets)
An arc's destructor removes its id from the arcs set of the nodes it connected.

Now i'm writing node's destructor. It should call each arc's destructor until its set is empty. I cannot iterate through the set with an iterator, since every step the arc destructor is removing its id from the set itself.

Hence i'd need to always access last element until the set is empty; but std::set does not allow indexing like arrays and vectors, and it doesn't have a "back" like lists and stacks. How can i do that?

relevant code:

```
graph::arc::~arc()
    {
    owner->list_node[n1]->remove_arc(id);
    owner->list_node[n2]->remove_arc(id);
    owner->list_arc[id] = nullptr;
    }
graph::node::~node()
    {
    while (!list_arc.empty())
        {
        owner->remove_arc(list_arc[list_arc.size()-1]); //invalid, that's roughly what i want to achieve
        }
    owner->list_node[id] = nullptr;
    }
```

Notes
owner is the graph object. owner->list_(node/arc) holds the actual pointers. Each item's id is equal to its position in graph's list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels like an error-prone cleanup strategy, but an improvement would probably require rewriting significantly more than what is provided in the question. (I suspect that shared and weak pointers could simplify things.) Since I lack enough information to suggest a better data structure:

For a set, it's easier to access the *first* element, `*list_arc.begin()`, than the last. (Not a huge difference, but still easier.)

Comment: I'm sticking with the set because of it being sorted for each insertion. The point is, node deletion shouldn't happen that frequently so i'm fine if its a bit more overhead-ish than other operations. Also i want to allow arcs deletions, so the arc destructor actually needs to remove its reference from the nodes it touches. That's what made the node deletion become weird. Also i'm using an indexing layer more because it's easier for me to work around with it, but it's easily replaceable with pointers once i'm done with all the logics. Thanks for the answer, i'll try with the begin way.

Comment: @Barnack Using a set is not incompatible with using smart pointers to simplify the cleanup.

Comment: why use smart pointers when you are 100% sure there will be no memory leacks in a specific portion of code? Looks like a pointless overhead to me-

Comment: @Barnack Smart pointers make your cleanup code simpler: easier to write, easier to read, and easier to maintain. (They also -- as a secondary feature -- avoid several situations where memory is leaked despite someone being 100% sure that there are no leaks.) The overhead tends to be similar to what is needed to manually avoid memory leaks.